# Accessing 2D array elements using double pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Recently I had an Interview in `C`. The interviewer has asked me to explain 
how to access particular element in `2D array` using `double pointer`. I gave the answer as `*(*(a+i)+j)`, where `a` is a double pointer, `i` is number of rows and `j` is number of columns. Later he asked me to explain using an example. I am confused at `*(a+i)` as it gives value instead of address and adding to `j` gives some junk value. 
Can anyone please explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that in a 1D array `a[i]` equals `*(a+i)`. And there are no 2D arrays in C, just arrays of arrays.

So `a[i][j]` is actually equal to `*(*(a+i)+j)`.

If the type of `a` is `int**`, then the type of `(a+i)` is still `int**`, you need to dereference it. Type of `*(a+i)` is `int*` and the type of `*(*(a+i)+j)` is `int`.

About the interview question, no matter that `a` is a double pointer, you should still use the `[]` notation. The alternative is too cumbersome:

```
int **a = ...;
int x = a[i][j];
```

Comment: *"there are no 2D arrays in C"* is somewhat incorrect. Double pointer `int **a;` can be used as 2D array with array of arrays approach, but `int a[N][M];` is true 2D array.

Comment: @user694733: Well, that's a matter of definition. `int a[N][M]` can be seen as a 2D array or as an array of N values of type `int[M]`, that is an array of arrays. Other languages that have true 2D arrays would use `a[i,j]` instead of `a[i][j]`.

Answer (score 3):

The a[i][j] element looks like

> a[i][j]=*(*(a+i)+j)

So it is a double pointer because it first determines the row and then the column, as you can see the 2d matrix looks like

```
-----       _________________
|___| ---> |___|____|____|___|
|___| ---> |___|____|____|___|
|___| ---> |___|____|____|___|
|___| ---> |___|____|____|___|
```

actually you can see that a one dimensional which holds the address of another one dimensional matrix. So the first vertical matrix data type is `int**` because it holds the address another one dimensional which is `int*`