# Access violation reading from double pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to code for Spiral Matrix where the input is a 2D array. When trying to simulate the code using double pointer i get 'Access Violation Reading' exception. Referred couple of links and tried different syntax but exception is not resolved.
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187430/accessing-2d-array-elements-using-double-pointer) [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970159/accessing-a-2d-array-using-double-pointer-to-function-c-language)

This is the exact code snippet which is throwing exception when debugging in VS2015.

```
void SpiralMatrix(int **arr, int row, int col)
{
    int u = 0, l = 0, r = col-1, d = row - 1;
    int val = arr[0][0];// *(*(arr + 0) + 0); // Throwing exception at this location

    printf("%d",val);
}


int main()
{
    int arr[2][3] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6} };
    SpiralMatrix((int **)arr,2,3);
}
```

I am really getting confused what am i missing here? I am trying to understand the root cause rather than the solution.

Comment: You can't cast arr to (int **)

Comment: Remove the `(int **)` from the calling statement in `main()`   This will cause the compiler to diagnose the problem  (the `(int **)` forces the compiler to shut up, and accept a conversion it would otherwise reject).

Comment: arr is really `int*` but not `int**` you can use `SpiralMatrix((int *)arr,2,3);` say. in your case `arr[0]` is 1 - so `arr[0][0]` is equal `*(int*)1` - of course exception